# Add alias to index from template?

Tags: elasticsearch

How do you add an alias to an index using a template?

If I look at my current templates there are empty sections named aliases in mappings and in the parent of mappings.  I can't seem to find much documentation indicating their use.  What I'm hoping to do is not have to execute an alias add after the index is created.

Thanks,
Pat

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When creating an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html), the `aliases` section contains the aliases that you want to be created at the same time a new index is created. For instance, with the command below, every time a new index whose name matches `index*` is created, then the aliases named `my_alias1` and `my_alias2` are also created at the same time.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/my_template -d '
{
    "template" : "index*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "aliases" : {
        "my_alias1" : {},
        "my_alias2" : {}
    }
}'
```

*UPDATE*

Note that as of ES6, `template` has been renamed to `index_patterns`:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/my_template -d '
{
    "index_patterns" : "index*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "aliases" : {
        "my_alias1" : {},
        "my_alias2" : {}
    }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Through trial and error I eventually was able to figure that out.  Any chance you know what the aliases field that is in the mapping object is for?

Comment: Can you clarify which "aliases field" you're referring to?

Comment: It must be an error, but for some reason we have a template that looks like the following:  "template_name": { "template": "prefix*", "mappings": "aliases": {} }, "aliases": {} }

Comment: That's not valid JSON, so that must definitely be an error.

Comment: Is there a way to create a alias based on a value ? I need to create a index in runtime and the alias will not always be the same but depend on the index url. Can I achieve it ?

Comment: @AshishPandey I suggest you create a new question which will get better visibility than a comment. Then you can link it from here

Comment: Thanks @Val. I have a new question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534772/adding-alias-to-index-in-elastic-search-template-runtime