# Adding alias to index in elastic search template runtime

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to add an alias to the index in elasticsearch template, but the alias is not always fixed. Its prepended by a client id. Due to the size of the data, we are creating monthly indexes for each client separately, and I want a single to query the data from all monthly indexes. However, because each client has different indexes, the alias has to prepended by clientId. How can I achieve this?

Eg: my indexes are:

`client1_01_18_user_location/user_location`, `client1_02_18_user_location/user_location`

and

`client2_01_18_user_location/user_location`, `client2_02_18_user_location/user_location`

The data for the month of January goes to 1st index, and for Feb goes to 2nd index in each client's case. I want an alias `client1_ul` or `client2_ul` to be created, based on, for which client the data is being inserted.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I did not fully understand your question. You can easily create an alias for existing index with `PUT /client1_01_18_user_location/_alias/client1_ul`. Is there some problem with this approach?

Comment: No. But because, these are monthly indexes, and I do not want someone to keep an eye on creating monthly indexes before the data is written to the index, I want to register a template which creates the index with a prefined mapping and alias, anytime, the index is not found, while writing the data.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve with a POST like this:

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "client1*", "alias" : "client1_ul" } }
    ]
}
```

This call will add all the index of the form client1* to the alias client1_ul, that can be used to query all the months.

You will need a POST for each user.

Otherwise, you can use a index [template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) for each client, if not all the indexes are present when you add the alias. The template can provide an alias:

```
PUT _template/template_1
{
    "index_patterns" : ["client1*"],
    "mappings" : {
        ... optional
    },
    "aliases" : {
        "client1_ul" : {}
    }
}
```

In this way the alias will be added to each index at the index creation, automatically by elasticsearch.

Comment: But there are other indexes in the system too, that start with client1_, and are not monthly indexes, so I can't do it like this.